# Unable to start Alfresco server because of RenditionServiceException

Tags: alfresco

I am facing issue in restarting alfresco server(4.2.e community version on linux). I am getting following error in alfresco.logs when I am trying to start alfresco server.

**Background:**
Alfresco running instance started acting weirdly, it was not allowing any user to login. Then I have started investigation and it seems like it was because server was running out of space. I have freed up some space. Then I was also getting solr index error. I have deleted solr indexes as well. 
Deleted work and temp folders as well.

Has any one come across this kind of error?any workarounds?

```
14:48:58,999 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 11050015 Unable to find rendering action root node.
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.checkRenderingActionRootNodeExists(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:232)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:187)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findOrCreateActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:157)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionServiceImpl.java:408)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:173)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:160)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:323)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitions(ThumbnailRegistry.java:159)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle$1.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:480)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle.onBootstrap(ThumbnailRegistry.java:476)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:435)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
14:49:00,558 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] Error trying to query Open Office version information. OpenOffice.org's ConfigurationRegistry not implemented in this version of OOo. This should not affect the operation of OOo.
14:49:00,561 INFO  [org.alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] The OpenOffice connection was re-established.
org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 11050015 Unable to find rendering action root node.
```

Comment: Have you been monkeying around with the data dictionary and/or the database? The error seems to imply that you have deleted a core Alfresco node from within the data dictionary

Comment: @Gagravarr, I agree it seems like that but I really have not touched anything,in fact the reason I restarted was because I was not able to login to alfresco. :). Any work around ?

Comment: You could try to comment out the spring bean for `ThumbnailRegistry` plus everything else that depends on it, get a half-working repository up, then re-create the missing node, but it's not really a beginner-friendly thing to tackle... Depends on what other bits of the repository went walkies at the same time, which'll depend on what actually did the deleting. Do any fellow admins of the system have a very guilty look? Any logs give a hint of who deleted this + maybe other system nodes, and why?

Comment: "guilty look", ;) Nothing like that. There are very less chance someone has toched that. I had also thought of trying after removal of ThumbnailRegistry dependency but it seems there are lot many dependancy to manage. May be will spin-off new instance as a last option.